# Verify solution of differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is an exercise (problem 1. c) of the textbook: Differential equations with applications 3rd ed. by Simmons.

Verify that the following function $y^2=e^{(2x)}+C$ is a solution of the ODE: $yy'=e^{(2x)}$

I was trying to first express $y$ explicitly by:
$$y=\pm\sqrt{e^{2x}+C}$$

And then calculate $y'$.
But it seems this is not the right way of solving this problem.

It turns out the question is very easy to solve by taking derivative on both side of the function:

$$2y*y'=2e^{2x}$$
and divide both size by $2$:
$$yy'=e^{2x}$$

Verified!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What happens if you take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$?

Comment: I am sorry that I asked a question that is so easy to solve LOL, but thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C \in \mathbb{R}$ and $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ some interval, such that a function $y: I \to \mathbb{R}$ with $y^2 = e^{2x} + C$ exists and is differentiable. Then by product or chain rule $2y(x)y'(x)=(y^2)'(x) = 2e^{2x}$. Now devide both sides by $2$.

Comment: Why did you downvote?

Comment: It's not me that downvoted...upvoted to cancel that...